# Trigonometric hyperbolic function - sinhx

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

It is given that $\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ which is given in various sources, however it has not been explained diagramatically or I am unable to get the derivation of these functions.

So, I request you to please explain me about this relation , I will be greatful to you.

Else refer me any source book for this, where this has been explained diagramatically and derivation is also available.

Thanks again..

Comment: also note that $x^2 + (iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2$, the hyperbola in real xy plane looks like circle in complex plane and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There's complete proof over [here](http://www.kaushikshankar.com/documents/Deriving_the_Definition_of_the_Hyperbolic_Trigonometric_Functions_and_Their_Identities_V2.pdf) and [here](http://planetmath.org/derivationofformulasforhyperbolicfunctionsfromdefinitionofhyperbolicangle). You will  see that $\sinh \alpha$ is vertical component and $\cosh \alpha$ is the horizontal component. (As the figure also speaks)

Comment: thanks a lot..that was of great help...

Answer (score 0):

Given any function $f(x)$, there are unique functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that $g(x)$ is even (that is, $g(-x)=g(x)$), $h(x)$ is odd (that is, $h(-x)=-h(x)$), and $f=g+h$.

If $f(x)=e^x$, then $g(x)$ is the hyperbolic cosine, and $h(x)$ is the hyperbolic sine.